# About integer solution a+b+c=2

Tags: matlab, combinatorics

For equation `a+b+c=2, a,b,c>=0`, is there a MATLAB function which can return the integer solutions in array? That is:

```
[0 0 2; 0 2 0; 2 0 0; 0 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 0]
```

Note for `a1+a2+..an=k, ai,k>=0`, there are `(n-1+k)!/((n-1)!*k!)` different integer solutions.

Comment: No, but there are several submissions on File Exchange that will give you partitions of an integer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the Symbolic Math Toolbox, you can use the [`combinat::compositions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/combinat-compositions.html) MuPAD function. You can use it directly in MuPAD or [call it from MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html) as well:

```
>> x = evalin(symengine, 'combinat::compositions(2, Length=3, MinPart=0)')
x =
[ [2, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 2]]
```

You can then convert the returned symbolic vars to cell array of numbers:

```
>> x = arrayfun(@double, x, 'Uniform',false)
x = 
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]

>> celldisp(x)
x{1} =
     2     0     0
x{2} =
     1     1     0
x{3} =
     1     0     1
x{4} =
     0     2     0
x{5} =
     0     1     1
x{6} =
     0     0     2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, is there a way to easily mirror the points along the axes? for example [ 1 1 1] can have 8 mirrors:[1 1 1;1 1 -1;1 -1 1...]

Comment: @law_light hmm, here's a quick implementation: http://pastebin.com/MPGpuHcb. It works for any length.

Comment: Huge thanks!!! impressive!